# How Can I Represent These Progressions in Sigma Notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I would like to represent the following finite progressions in sigma notation:

1. $Finding\ the \ n^{th} \ term \ of \ a \ geometric \ progression$: $a_n=a_1(r^{n-1})$, where $a_1$ is the first time and $r$ is the common ratio
2. $The \ sum \ of \ a \ geometric \ progression: \ S_n=a_1\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$
3. $Determining \ the \ n^{th} \ term \ of \ an \ arithmetic \ progression: a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$,
   $\ $ where $d$ is the common difference
4. And finally, the sum of an arithmetic progression: $S_n=\frac{n}{2}(2a_1+(n-1)d)$

Comment: Have you attempted to write the sum of a geometric progression or an arithmetic progression in summation notation?  Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: For a geometric progression of the $n^{th}$ term, the best I got is $\sum_{k=a_1}^{a_n} ar^{n}$
but that hasn't worked very well at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to expression the sum of the first $n$ terms of an geometric progression and the sum of the first $n$ terms of an arithmetic progression in summation notation.

**Sum of a geometric progression:**  If the initial term is $a_1$ and the common ratio is $r$, then the $k$th term of the geometric progression is $a_k = a_1r^{k - 1}$.  Hence, the sum of the first $n$ terms of the geometric progression is 
$$S_n  = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_1r^{k - 1} = \begin{cases}
a_1 \dfrac{1 - r^n}{1 - r} & \text{if $r \neq 1$}\\
na_1 & \text{if $r = 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Notice that the index of the variable must be different from the index of the upper limit.  Otherwise, all $n$ terms in the sum would be equal to $a_1r^{n - 1}$.

**Sum of an arithmetic progression:** If the initial term is $a_1$ and the common difference is $d$, then the $k$th term of the arithmetic progression is $a_k = a_1 + (k - 1)d$.  Hence, the sum of the first $n$ terms of the arithmetic progression is 
$$S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} [a_1 + (k - 1)d] = \frac{n}{2}[2a_1 + (n - 1)d] = \frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$$

Comment: Is k=1 a mistake? When I put k=1 into your equation the argument ends up being raised to the power of 0, which just makes the entire argument equal to 1. The same issue applies to the arithmetic progression.

Or am I not understanding what the index means?

Comment: Perhaps you do not understand what the index means.  For the sum of the first $n$ terms of the geometric progression, \begin{align*} S_1  & = \sum_{k = 1}^{1} a_1r^{k - 1} = a_1r^0 = a_1\\ S_2 & = \sum_{k  = 1}^{2} a_1r^{k - 1} = a_1r^0 + a_1r^1 = a_1 + a_1r = a_1(1 + r)\\ S_3 & = \sum_{k = 1}^{3} a_1r^{k - 1} = a_1r^0 + a_1r^1 + a_1r^2 = a_1(1 + r + r^2)\end{align*}

Comment: Alright, so suppose we have the geometric series
$$2+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8},...$$
and we are to find the sum of the first 10 terms.
Using the algebraic method, I get $\approx3.996$

How would I do this with your equation? Could you explain the steps?

Comment: Take $a_1 = 2$ and $r = 1/2$ in the formula $S_n = a_1 \frac{1 - r^n}{1  - r}$ to obtain $$S_{10}  =2 \frac{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 2\frac{1 - \frac{1}{1024}}{\frac{1}{2}} =  4\frac{1024 - 1}{1024} = \frac{1023}{256}$$

Comment: Thank you. I see that now. Also if it's not too much, I would appreciate if you answered the rest of the question as well, which is finding the $n^{th}$ term of a geometric and arithmetic progression, and not just finding the sum of the first $n$ terms

Comment: The $n$th term of an arithmetic progression with initial term $a_1$ and common difference $d$ is $a_n = a_1 + (n - 1)d$.  If you insist on writing $a_n$ as a sum, you could write $a_n = a_1 - d + \sum_{k = 1}^{n} d$.  The $n$th term of a geometric progression with initial term $a_1$ and common ratio $r$ is $a_n = a_1r^{n - 1}$.   If $r \neq 0$, you could write $a_n = \frac{a_1}{r} \prod_{k = 1}^{n} r$, where $\prod$ means product.